# Is it legal to use a laser to protect privacy vs. CCTV camera?

Tags: privacy, is-x-legal

Alice has a garden that is not overlooked by any windows, but is next door to a commercial car park that has a [CCTV camera on a pole](https://previews.123rf.com/images/aonskynotlimit/aonskynotlimit1507/aonskynotlimit150700081/58340457-%E3%83%9D%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AE%E5%B1%8B%E5%A4%96%E3%83%89%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E9%98%B2%E7%8A%AF%E3%82%AB%E3%83%A1%E3%83%A9.jpg) within a plastic hemisphere that does not allow an observer to see where the camera is pointing.  She would like to sunbathe, but is concerned she will be watched by the CCTV operator.  To prevent this she sets up a [Class IIIa/3R laser pointer](https://www.lasersafetyfacts.com/resources/Spreadsheet---laser-classes.pdf) located at her sunbed pointing at the camera.  Her assumption is that if the camera is not looking at her it will have no effect, but if it is it will [blind but not damage it](https://ipvm.com/reports/lasers-cameras).

What is the legality of Alice's actions?  Any jurisdiction would be interesting.

Comment: On the other hand if Alice asked the park managers to put a screen in front of the camera to cover the angle towards her garden, and the managers refused, could she sue them for privacy violation?

Answer (score 3):

## It's illegal to (temporarily) break an item

The commercial car park owner may not aim the camera at Alice garden. However, even *if* it does so, breaking the camera or damaging it is still illegal - as one of the various forms of destruction/damaging of property colloquially called vandalism.

Do note that the very article and the clasification of laser OP links to points out that *even a low-powered "pet-safe" IIIb/3R laser leaves out burnt-out pixels with a pinkish surrounding. These might not be enough to prevent identification when not aiming the laser into the camera, but they are damage to the sensor. The very article *also* describes how the camera damage progresses even after exposure, possibly due to the high power lasers.

[image]

However, even if no such damage occurs, the owner of the camera is (temporarily) deprived of its legal uses while the laser is pointed on it, which is in many jurisdictions enough to count as theft.

Comment: Since apparently the laser has only done "minor" harm to the camera, does that also mean that it would be totally useless for the intended cause (preventing the camera seeing the garden)?

Comment: @PMF while the laser is pointed at the camera, there is *nothing* to be seen but a bright light, but the image above is the lasting damage left by those low powered lasers.